# DeployR: How to install R packages

Tags: r, deployr

I'm  using DeployR for Microsoft R Server 2016, 8.0.5 for Windows.

I would like to install package XLConnect for work with Excel files:

```
> install.packages("XLConnect")
package 'XLConnect' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Windows\Temp\RtmpYnppvI\downloaded_packages

> library("XLConnect")
Console Error there is no package called 'XLConnect'
API Error there is no package called 'XLConnect'
```

What could be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `library(XLConnect)`, see also the [readxl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

If we are working with `deployR`, there is a package named `deployrUtils` which already has the `deployrPackage` function to load and install the package (if not present)

```
library(deployrUtils)
deployrPackage("XLConnect")
```

Below is the code snippet for `deployrPackage`

```
deployrPackage <- function(pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"), ...) {
  #
  # this function checks to see if the declared pkgs are installed. If not, 
  # pkgs are installed. In all cases the packages are loaded
  #
  if (!suppressWarnings(require(pkgs, character.only = TRUE))) {
    install.packages(pkgs, lib, repos = repos, ...)
    if(!suppressWarnings(require(pkgs, character.only = TRUE))) {
      stop("Package not found")
    }
  }

  suppressWarnings(require(pkgs, character.only = TRUE))
}
```

More info about the different functions in `deployrUtils` can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/deployrUtils)

Comment: Thank you, I understand, but I figured now that even with `deployrPackage("XLConnect")` get the same message, so any package that I try to load does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Anette  Please check your configuration.  It should work based on the guidelines and I also use deployR

Comment: Yes, sure. Well I'm new in deployR. I don't have Admin permissions, so I guess the problem is because of that?

Comment: @Anette Yes, it could be due to that.

Comment: Some time has passed and I'm trying to solve the problem again...unfortunately I still can't install any of new packages on DeployR. I moved `XLConnect_0.2-11.zip` to libraries (`.libPaths()`) and unpacked it, so installed.packages() contains `XLConnect` then. But I know, on this way new package is not installed properly.. I also trying to install packages through Interactive API Explorer (tab Packages).

Comment: @Anette  Now with Microsoft R server 9.0.1, it is called operationalization with more features and easy deployment by calling a single line code with msrdeploy package

Comment: Yes. Nevertheless I'm insisting to solve installing. But I see, that I will have to try 9.0.1.

Comment: There is a problem with installing `XLConnect` also in 9.0.1. My code is: `REMOTE> install.packages("XLConnect")`, and then `library("XLConnect")`, but get an error: `Package or namespace load failed for 'XLConnect'`

Comment: @Anette  I am not sure about the error.  If you have an older version, remove that and then do a fresh install